# Add JavaScript using CSS 'Content' Style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a certain web application with a page that is procedurally generated using table data from a database, and the only customization I have over how it functions is with the CSS that's used to stlye the results.

I'd like to know if it's possible to insert a javascript action into part of the page using a CSS content style.

As an example, it would look something like the below:

```
.actioncatalogwrapper:after{
    content: (Javascript here);
}
```

I have some questions about how this would function, though:

- Do I need to escape quotes in my Javascript, to use it inside of a Content style?
- Is what I'm asking for even possible? What would this look like, if not exactly pasting the javascript as the data for the content style?

The script looks like the below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('ul ul').hide(); 
  $('.description').hide(); 
  $('h2').click(function() { 
    $(this).siblings().slideToggle(); 
    $('ul ul ul').slideDown();
    $(this).parent().siblings().children().next().slideUp();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: not possible...

Comment: Oh, darn.... Why not?

Comment: Because it's simply not something that browsers do. Why not just add the script to the page and run it as a "load" event handler (or whatever's appropriate)?

Comment: this is not possible.  Btw, what is the relationship between the script you posted and CSS? Why do you need to add it inside CSS and not just execute the browser on load of the page?

Comment: The reason I'm asking about adding the script via CSS is because I have no control over the HTML content of the page and can't manually add the script.
The page is generated automatically as part of an ITSM application that I customize for clients at work. We have control over the CSS that's used to style the page and the results shown on the page, but no control over the actual content of the page and so we couldn't just modify the HTML being used for the page to add a script that way, as we didn't develop the app that generates the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.

See the spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-content

> Generated content does not alter the document tree. In particular, it
>   is not fed back to the document language processor (e.g., for
>   reparsing).